# Legal considerations of analyzing and training language models with online public documents

Tags: nlp

When training and evaluating my language models, I always wish to have more data, especially those from different sectors.

Then, I noticed [the following statement about copyright](https://www.state.gov/copyright-information/) on the US government website,
"Unless a copyright is indicated, information on State Department websites is in the public domain and may be copied and distributed without permission."

Is it legal to train language models with documents subject to this statement and, more interestingly, write Medium posts or publish papers to present the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The public domain (PD) consists of all the creative work to which no exclusive intellectual property rights apply. Those rights may have expired, been forfeited, expressly waived, or may be inapplicable. Because no one holds the exclusive rights, anyone can legally use or reference those works without permission.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain

With works in public domain you are able to do what you want.